# proxy in selenium using firefox geckodriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy

```
import requests
from itertools import cycle
from lxml.html import fromstring

def get_proxies():
    url = 'https://free-proxy-list.net/'
    response = requests.get(url)
    parser = fromstring(response.text)
    proxies = set()
    for i in parser.xpath('//tbody/tr')[:10]:
        if i.xpath('.//td[7][contains(text(),"yes")]'):
            proxy = ":".join([i.xpath('.//td[1]/text()')[0], i.xpath('.//td[2]/text()')[0]])
            proxies.add(proxy)
    return proxies


url="https://api.ipify.org?format=json"
x=requests.get(url,proxies={"http": next(proxy_pool), "https": next(proxy_pool)})
print(x.json())
```

and response was {u'ip': u'87.228.29.154'}

I was able to get address of proxy ip while making python request
But I wanted to do that in selenium I tried several solutions like

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", "190.186.58.198")
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", 53281)
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

But on visiting the url I get my own ip .Is there any way that I get the selected ip on checking

Comment: Have you tried using the proxy outside of selenium to ensure that it works?

Comment: edited the question json returned ip was coming from https://free-proxy-list.net/

Comment: But you cant ensure that the IP proxy actually works, if it doesn't work selenium will use your IP

Comment: no problem I will go first op ip checking url and make a check as well

Comment: Yeah sorry, misread your comment

Comment: any possibilites?:-)

Comment: I've not a clue unfortunately, sorry!

Comment: ok,no problem :-)